# Accessibility of XAMPP either with usb plugged into the pc and use pc's internet connection or vice versa

Tags: android, networking, xampp

I have no networking background. I would like to apologize if the terms that I used in my question below are incorrect. Your help is appreciated.
1)   Recently, I am developing an android app which involves google map api and xampp. I can access database on the phone browser(192.168.x.x:8080/folder/getdetail.php) when my android phone (4.1.2) is connected to my pc and used my pc's internet connection. But after I unplugged the usb from my pc and used wifi, I no longer can access the same link as mentioned  above on my phone. May I know what is the problem and what tools or skills that I need to look for? 

(2)  If the above mentioned problem is solved, I am also looking forward on the way to make xampp to be accessible over the internet. For instance, my pc serves as a server at home and I can connect to the server and retrieve some data from the db when i am elsewhere. 


P/S: My pc is using wireless internet connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there's too few information on your network and your pc. Let's assume you're using your Windows-PC and Phone on the same Network and you didn't change any web server settings and didn't move the XAMPP folder.

XAMPP is running an apache Server which is listening on TCP Port 80.

First you should check your firewall. Windows is using 3 different Profiles.

if you connect your phone and an additional network is set up with a different profile this could be the reason.

http://www.windows7library.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2011/06/Network-and-Sharing-Center.jpg

If you want to access your XAMMP from the internet you should forward a TCP port to port 80 on your PCs LAN IP-Address.

http://en.kioskea.net/contents/280-nat-network-address-translation-port-forwarding-and-port-trigg
http: //en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding

But please only do that for testing purpose since outdated webservers/modules/scripts can actually harm your system. Use XAMPP only for development and testing.
My advice if you still want to do it forward some other port >10000 to your local port 80.

To access it you have to add the port to your url like this http: //127.0.0.1:8080/